# more than 2 values passed by table view cell

Tags: xcode, uitableview

How can I have more than 2 values held by my table view cell? What I want to happen is when I click a cell in my table view, it will pass 3 values to the next view. But I can only get two values (name, address) because they are contained in the textlabel and detailtextlabel but the (phone) is not being showed in my cells, only name and address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u want to display more value in cell the create custom cell.

Option is use NSMutableArray with like below and show all values in custom cell:

```
 NSMutableArray *arrValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:"Value1","Value2","Value3"],nil];
```

Add as many array into arrValues.

Now when tableViewDidSelectAtRow 's method: pass this array to next controller

```
NSArray *arrPassing = [arrValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: yes i have considered creating a custom cell but is there no other way? like using only default cell, using only textlabel and detailtextlabel and then have something like a hidden variable to store the 3rd value that is not included in the cell visually.

Comment: U show your 2 values in default cell and other will not be showed and structure your value array as i have mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom cell for the tableview cell